# Delimiter with Java line of Input

Tags: java, delimiter

Hopefully this is very simple for someone, but I can't seem to work it out.

Trying to use an input of:

```
addperson jsmith,john,smith
```

So far I have used two `Scanner` objects with different delimiters, but I can't get it to work.
I don't want to scan whole line and split string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Delim
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inputCommand = new Scanner(System.in);
        input.useDelimiter(",");
        inputCommand.useDelimiter(" ");
        System.out.println("Enter a username: (format username,name, surname)");
        list.add(inputCommand.next());               
        list.add(input.next());
        list.add(input.next());
        list.add(input.next());
        System.out.println("//debug: command " + list.get(0));
        printName(list);


    }

    static void printName(ArrayList arr)
    {
        System.out.println("username: " + arr.get(1) + "\nname: " + arr.get(2) + "\nsurname: " + arr.get(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: `I don't want to scan whole line and split string.` Why not?

Comment: Just think it could be messy. Need to sometimes take a command but no extra arguments.

Comment: This is far messier that `split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single scanner with a custom delimiter:

```
input.useDelimiter("[,\\s]");
```

This makes the delimiter either a comma or a whitespace character.

So, your overall program would be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Delim
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        input.useDelimiter("[,\\s]");
        System.out.println("Enter a username: (format username,name,surname)");
        list.add(input.next());               
        list.add(input.next());
        list.add(input.next());
        list.add(input.next());
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println("//debug: command " + list.get(0));
        printName(list);


    }

    static void printName(ArrayList arr)
    {
        System.out.println("username: " + arr.get(1) + "\nname: " + arr.get(2) + "\nsurname: " + arr.get(3));
    }
}
```

Comment: @GlenBest Thanks.  (But isn't it good coding practice to leave outdated and nonexistent variables still declared?!? `:P`)

Comment: @anorton you a bloody legend! I is working exactly as I want.

Comment: @anorton what exactly do the [] square brackets do in the delimiters? And do you know where I can learn a bit more about delimiters?
Thanks

Comment: @oCodaa The `Scanner` delimiters follow [RegEx syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). That's where the `[]` come into play.  Basically, it says "match any of these characters."  The comma is self-explanatory.  `\\s` is some arbitrary whitespace.  The biggest watchout for using RegEx in Java is that whenever the RegEx says `\s` is whitespace, you have to type `\\s` to escape the `\` in Java.

Comment: @oCodaa Since you're relatively new here, I thought I'd let you know about the "accept" feature for this site.  As the questioner, you can "accept" any one post as the one that best answer for your question.  This pins the post to the top of the answers list, marks the question as answered, gives the answerer +15 reputation, and earns you +2 reputation.

Comment: @anoton I need a little more help. Essentially same code as above, but how can I get it to intake 4 or 5 input.

Comment: e.g 2 types of input 
input:
    addperson john,joj,smith
or:
    addperson john,joj,smith,10

Comment: @oCodaa When you're on the 5th input piece, check if it's `addperson` or the other possibility.  If it's `addperson`, start a new line.  if it's the other possibility, do whatever is appropriate for that...

Comment: @anorton ok. I can get it to work with command + 3 or 4 inputs:
e.g addperson jj,john,johnson
AND addperson jj, john, jeramy, johnson
but I also want to be able to just enter: 
addperson (and the program just recognise it) do I change the delimiter?? Thanks