# Using a delimiter to extract a hyperlink - Java

Tags: java, project, delimiter

I'm a novice at java and I'm working on a project that scans the source code of a website, and extracts all the hyperlinks contained in it.
So far I have my project working so that it scans every 'word' of the source code using a Scanner (in.next())
However Ive been told to use delimiters to extract the hyperlinks from this, but I can barely find any information out there to help me use them!
Someone couldnt help explain to me delimiters and how I could use them in this project? It would be really appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class HyperlinkMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        String URL = in.next();

        URL website = new URL(URL);
        Scanner inWebsite = new Scanner (website.openStream());

        String inputLine; 

        while ((inWebsite.hasNext())) {
            // Process each 'word'.
            System.out.println(inWebsite.next());

        }
        in.close(); 

    } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
        System.out.println(me); 

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser and XPaths.

Comment: [This looks like a very similar issue to yours... Does it answer the question?][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356213/delimiter-with-java-line-of-input

Comment: What kind of delimiter are you looking for? You might just search for "href=".

Comment: I've been studying computing for around a month now and I have no idea what they are. My teacher said specifically to use delimiters to extract the hyperlinks, I don't suppose you know how they work?

Comment: Basically i'm looking for a delimiter that finds the start of the link "<a href" " then finds the end of it " "" > "

Comment: Then use an HTML parser, like JSoup

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regular expression on strings.  Below is an existing Stack Overflow on this topic.

[How to use regular expressions to parse HTML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)